# Dos Select con condicion dentro de una misma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una consulta que he realizado en dos consultas diferentes y me gustaría poder realizarla en una y no se como podría hacerlo.

```
SELECT
User.Telefono,
FROM
Premio
INNER JOIN `User` ON Premio.user_id = `User`.id;

SELECT
User.Telefono,
FROM
Premio
INNER JOIN `User` ON Premio.user_id = `User`.id
where utilizado=1;
```

En una me da todos los telefonos de los usuarios, y en la otra me da todos los teléfonos que han usado el premio, yo lo que quiero es que con una consulta me muestre, en una columna el listado de todos los teléfonos y en otra columna el listado de todos los teléfonos que han usado el premio.

- Todos los Telefonos
- 645987232
- 698376238
- Telefonos Usados
- 698376238

Algo así, alguna sugerencia de como podría realizarlo, sin tener que usar dos consultas distintas?
Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tu quieres no se puede hacer, lo que tienes que obtener es una lista con todos los teléfonos y al lado el campo donde ves si se ha utilizado o no el premio. Tendrías que hacerlo así:

```
SELECT
  User.Telefono,
  Premio.utilizado
FROM
  User
LEFT JOIN `Premio` ON `User`.id = Premio.user_id
WHERE Premio.utilizado = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo primero que deseas, referente a una columna para cada uno, se me ocurre que utilices tanto una vista (`VIEW`) como una consulta con un `LEFT JOIN`.

Esta vista será la consulta principal de la cual agarrarán las próximas. La creo así.

```
CREATE VIEW Principal AS
SELECT
    User.id as 'id',
    User.Telefono as 'telefono',
    Premio.utilizado as 'utilizado'
FROM
    Premio
INNER JOIN User
    ON Premio.user_id = `User`.id;
```

Después utilizo un `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    Principal.telefono as 'telefonos',
    p2.telefono as 'usados'
FROM
    Principal
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                id,
                telefono
            FROM 
                Principal
            WHERE 
                utilizado = 1 ) p2
    ON Principal.id = p2.id
```

Y obtengo las columnas.

```
telefonos  |  usados
11111111   |  11111111
22222222   |  22222222
33333333   |  NULL
44444444   |  NULL
55555555   |  55555555
66666666   |  NULL
```

Algo que te daría un resultado semejante sería el uso del `IF`

```
SELECT
    telefono, as 'telefonos'
    IF(utilizado = 1,telefono, NULL) as 'usados'
FROM Principal;
```

Para lo que muestras como ejemplo, me parece que no son columnas sino "filas", entonces eso me recuerda a un `UNION` que podrías usar de esta manera.

```
SELECT
    'telefono' as 'descripcion',
    Principal.telefono as 'telefono'
FROM 
    Principal
UNION
SELECT
    'usado' as 'descripcion',
  Principal.telefono as 'telefono'
FROM
    Principal
WHERE Principal.utilizado = 1
```

Resultando algo como.

```
descripcion  |  telefono
telefono     |  11111111
telefono     |  22222222
telefono     |  33333333
telefono     |  44444444
telefono     |  55555555
telefono     |  66666666
usado        |  11111111
usado        |  22222222
usado        |  55555555
```

El truco principal en todas estas fue crear una `VIEW`, que es una consulta a la que se hace referencia. Si la deseas eliminar utiliza `DROP VIEW Principal`. Entonces, más que utilizar la consulta dos veces, utilizamos su "vista" dos veces en una sola consulta.

Ahora, que si deseas prescindir de la creación de una vista (`VIEW`) puedes poner la consulta de forma explícita.

```
SELECT
    telefono, as 'telefonos'
    IF(utilizado = 1,telefono, NULL) as 'usados'
FROM (  SELECT
            User.id as id,
            User.Telefono as 'telefono',
            Premio.utilizado as 'utilizado'
        FROM
            Premio
        INNER JOIN User
            ON Premio.user_id = `User`.id) as n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer que te salga con una sentencia select:

```
SELECT "Telefonos" as descripcion, User.Telefono as telefono

FROM Premio
INNER JOIN `User` ON Premio.user_id = `User`.id

UNION

SELECT "TelefonosPremiados" as descripcion, User.Telefono as telefono

FROM Premio
INNER JOIN `User` ON Premio.user_id = `User`.id
where utilizado=1;
```